# Excel Formula SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can anyone explain the meaning of the following formula?

`Summary` is an Excel tab name, and `forecast Submit` is also an excel tab name.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A85=Summary!$A$2:$A$144),'forecast Submit'!$C$2:$C$144)
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's see if we can break this down for you:

`Summary!$A$2:$A$144`

This notation means column A, rows 2-144, within the sheet `Summary`.  You can ignore the dollar signs (`$`) for now, because they're not actually changing your output.  At this point, you have a series of values, all in column `A`.

`A85=Summary!$A$2:$A$144`

This compares each item in `Summary!A2:A144` to the item in `A85`, and reports true if they are equal.  At this point, you have a series of `TRUE` and `FALSE` values, and you can imagine that they are sitting in some invisible new (temporary) column, somewhere off to the side.

`--()`

This converts boolean (true/false) values to `1`s and `0`s. A value of `TRUE` becomes `1` and a value of `FALSE` becomes `0`.

So now, our invisible column is filled with `1`s and `0`s.

`(sumproduct...)` multiplies numbers in corresponding rows, and then sums the results.  In practice, you are now multiplying values by 1 or 0, and summing the result.  Of course, anything multiplied by 0 is 0, and anything multiplied by 1 is itself.  So, in effect, the 0s you generated earlier are being used to ignore certain rows, and the 1s are being used to include the other rows.

Overall, it will add all of the numbers in `forecast Submit` for which the corresponding row in `Summary` is equal to `A85`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining; to futher under stand it,, i have a id number in Column A of summary tab D00020061, And same ID exists in forecast Submit tab under column A , And column c amount in forecast Submit tab is 170843.42,  But when I run the formula it gives me 10,415, not sure how i get 10,415?

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't understand your question.

Comment: so A85 = D00020061  --- No other row has that Id in Summary!A2:A144, so when i go to forecast Submit column A15 =D00020061, and  forecast Submit column C15 = 170843.42,,,,,, BACK ON MY Summary I85 = 10,415 ( which is my formula (=SUMPRODUCT(--(A85=Summary!$A$2:$A$144),'forecast Submit'!$C$2:$C$144))   I still don't know how I get 10,415 as answer

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot your sheet without being able to see it.  Am I correct in saying that that you are expecting a match but are not getting one?  

Have you tried using the Evaluate Formula feature of Excel?  It breaks down how formulas are resolved.

Comment: Thank you! This will get me started, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function

This should give you all the answers that you seek.